# [TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null]

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi I'm trying to use DocumentPicker however I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null

please note that I'm using expo

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is how import DocumentPicker :

```
import DocumentPicker from "react-native-document-picker";
```

This is my handleDocumentSelect:

```
const handleDocumentSelect = async () => {
try {
  const document = await DocumentPicker.pick()
  console.log(document);
} catch (error) {
  if (!DocumentPicker.isCancel(error)) {
    console.log("Error Take Document", error);
  }
}
};
```

my Pressable:

```
<Pressable
  onPress={handleDocumentSelect}
  style={[styles.btnContainer, style]}
>
  <View style={styles.iconContainer}>{icon}</View>
  <Text style={styles.btnTitle}>{btnTitle}</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned in the doc that `react-native-document-picker` is supported in Expo managed workflow through the usage of [custom development clients.](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/)

```
expo install react-native-document-picker

# Create a development build (provided you have expo-dev-client installed and set up)
eas build

# Or run it locally
expo prebuild
expo run:ios
expo run:android
```

Ref : [Expo workaround for react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker#expo)

Comment: i down grade from the latest version into 8.1.4 still got the same error, if i use the latest version the package did not work, already try using the eas build, etc still can't

Comment: Can you update question with your package.json file please

Comment: ok i'll add the package json

Comment: If latest version is not working try with version 8.2.1. Also please verify you have not missed anything to create a development build
https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/?redirected

Comment: already have eas.json do eas build in emulator but still not work. work on u Mr. Thanhal?

Comment: I am using react native cli & no issues there. For expo, the issue was already mentioned here : https://github.com/rnmods/react-native-document-picker/issues/644